# Console.WriteLine text from CodeDomProvider

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, codedom, system-codedom-compiler

I'm trying to use CodeDomProvider to make a C# compiler.
I managed to get the errors but i can't get the output.

This is what i have so far:

```
    public List<string> Errors(CompilerResults compilerResults)
    {
        List<string> messages = new List<string>();

        foreach (CompilerError error in compilerResults.Errors)
        {
            messages.Add(String.Format("Line {0} Error No:{1} - {2}", error.Line, error.ErrorNumber, error.ErrorText));
        }

        return messages;
    }

    public CompilerResults ProcessCompilation(string programText)
    {
        CodeDomProvider codeDomProvider = CodeDomProvider.CreateProvider("CSharp");
        CompilerParameters parameters = new CompilerParameters();
        parameters.GenerateExecutable = false;
        StringCollection assemblies = new StringCollection();
        return codeDomProvider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(parameters, programText);
    }
```

`CSharpCompiler` is the class that contains the functions from above

```
    public JsonResult Compiler(string code)
    {
        CSharpCompiler compiler = new CSharpCompiler();
        CompilerResults compilerResults = compiler.ProcessCompilation(code);

        Debug.WriteLine("OUTPUT----------------------------------------------");
        foreach (var o in compilerResults.Output)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(o);
        }

        List<string> compilerErrors = compiler.Errors(compilerResults);

        if (compilerErrors.Count != 0)
            return Json(new { success = false, errors = compilerErrors});

        return Json(true);
    }
```

`compilerResults.Output` is always empty.
If i run this piece of code:

```
using System;

public class HelloWorld
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello world!");
    }
}
```

What can i do to display the message "Hello world!"?

Answer (score 0):

`CompileAssemblyFromSource` creates, as its name implies, an assembly. To get access to the compiled code, you can use [the `CompilerResults.CompiledAssembly` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.codedom.compiler.compilerresults.compiledassembly) and then use reflection to find and invoke the `Main` method:

```
compilerResults.CompiledAssembly.GetType("HelloWorld").GetMethod("Main").Invoke(null, null);
```

Though if you set `parameters.GenerateExecutable` to `true`, you can simplify this to:

```
compilerResults.CompiledAssembly.EntryPoint.Invoke(null, null);
```